# SQL using max function in triple join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, left-join, inner-join

I have 3 Table. I want to join them all, I can do that. But when I try to use MAX function, I got error.

```
SELECT A.X, B.Y, SUBSTRING(str,CHARINDEX('C.Z',str)+12,4) as score,   MAX(A.Q)
FROM A(NOLOCK)
JOIN B
ON A.BID = B.id 
JOIN  C 
ON   B.Cid = C.ID
WHERE C.ApplicationDate BETWEEN '01-01-2013' AND GETDATE() 
group by B.Customer
```

If I don't write MAX function I get

**Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4**

### 1 , 1  , 1 ,  1

### 1  ,    2 ,  3  ,  5

### 1  ,    3  , 2  ,   7

### 2 , 3, 3, 1

2, 3 , 1, 5

### . , . , . , .

### . , . , . , .

I want to get col4's max value for col1's 1 value. For example 
I want to get 1,3,2,7 and 2,3,1,5 values in this example.

How can I do that. Thanks for your help.

edit

`SELECT InstanceID, CustomerNo, Date, SUBSTRING(str,CHARINDEX('TTHA',str)+12,4) as score, MAX(SecondDate) as 'SearchDate'
FROM application(NOLOCK)
JOIN application_info 
ON application.application_info_id = application_info.id 
JOIN  Request 
ON   application.request_id = Request.id
WHERE Request.Date BETWEEN '01-01-2000' AND GETDATE() 
group by InstanceID,CustomerNo,Date,SUBSTRING(str,CHARINDEX('TTHA',str)+12,4)`

I count not do your offers. Could you help me on my code ?

OUTPUT
[image: I want to get highlighted values]

Thanks

Comment: You need to `group by` everything in the `select` list that is not passed to an aggregate function, i.e. everything except `A.Q`

Comment: you would need to group by A.X, B.y and your substring on score. not sure why you're grouping just on customer when it's not even in the select.

Comment: Thanks, Error has gone but i still can't get max value of col4 for col1's same value. For example I got 6 rows 1-1-1-1-2-2 in col1. By the way I got 1-2-3-4-1-2 values in col 4. I want to get col1=1 col4=4(max one) and col1=2 col4 = 2(max one)

Comment: Perhaps Change `A(Nolock)` to `(Select X, max(Q) Q from A group by X) as A` and eliminate the max and group by's from the outer select.  you have to get the max first

Comment: What is  Z's max value?

Comment: col 4 ' s max value for same values of col1.

Comment: Even with the update, without knowing the source table for each column and the cardinality between the tables, this is nearly impossible.  The issue I think is that b and c tables have multiple records for a given record in A.  This is causing multiple values to appear for columns from tables B and C.  thus you need the max of A.Column grouped by the other a.Column before you join... So the set of data you are joining on is only the max values to begin with from table A.  But without table structure, sample data form each table and cardinaility I can't be certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace your `group by` statement to this

```
group by A.X, B.Y, SUBSTRING(str,CHARINDEX('C.Z',str)+12,4)
```

Comment: Thanks, Error has gone but i still can't get max value of col4 for col1's same value. For example I got 6 rows 1-1-1-1-2-2 in col1. By the way I got 1-2-3-4-1-2 values in col 4. I want to get col1=1 col4=4(max one) and col1=2 col4 = 2(max one). I don't want to get other values.

Comment: @Vins4nity please provide a proper output that you desired, so it will be easy to figure out and give you the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe: but without details on where each column in the select is sourced (table it comes from) I doubt it...

This assumes instance and secondDate are the only fields in Application we care about  If customerNo is in that table as well it would need to be added to the **inner select and group by.**

Assumptions:
InstanceID, and SecondDate are the only columns in Application wtihin the select.
The cardinality between application and either application_info or Request is causing multiple records to appear and when grouping on these values is causing improper results.

I'm guessing because in your example you have 5 columns in your select and only 4 in the output.  So I have no idea which column is missing.

```
SELECT InstanceID, CustomerNo, 
       Date, SUBSTRING(str,CHARINDEX('TTHA',str)+12,4) as score,  
       SecondDate as 'SearchDate'
FROM (SELECT instanceID, max(SecondDate) SecondDate 
      FROM application 
      GROUP BY instanceID) Application
JOIN application_info 
ON application.application_info_id = application_info.id 
JOIN  Request 
ON   application.request_id = Request.id
WHERE Request.Date BETWEEN '01-01-2000' AND GETDATE()
```